# Am I able to print out what the customer has ordered with this code?

Tags: java

Is there anyway to convert the int that the user is inputting which relates to an item on the menu into the actual item on the menu and then print out their order at the end?

`System.out.println(custStarter + custMain + custDessert + custDrink);` just gives me the numbers inputted added together.

Customer input must be a number relating to the item on the menu, eg 1 for Garlic bread etc.

Looking for the end product to be, if user was to input 1 (Garlic Bread) 4 (Fish and Chips), 7 (Ice Cream), 10 (Tea), for it to print "Your order is Garlic bread, fish and chips, ice cream and tea."

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String starterMeal[] = { "Garlic Bread", "Lentil Soup", "Prawn Cocktail" };
        String mainMeal[] = { "Fish and Chips", "Vegetarian Curry", "Cottage Pie" };
        String dessertMeal[] = { "Trio of ice-cream", "Apple Pie", "Cheesecake" };
        String drinkMeal[] = { "Tea", "Coffee", "Lemonade" };

        double starterPrice[] = { 4.50, 4.99, 9.99 };
        double mainPrice[] = { 12.50, 9.90, 11.50 };
        double dessertPrice[] = { 4.50, 3.50, 2.50 };
        double drinkPrice[] = { 2.99, 3.50, 2.50 };

        // Asking customer for their name + welcoming them to the cafe.

        System.out.println("Hello, can you tell me your name? ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name + ", welcome to our cafe!");

        // Code to display full menu to customer.

        System.out.println("Here is the full menu: ");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("\tStarters: ");
        System.out.println("1. Garlic Bread £4.50");
        System.out.println("2. Lentil Soup £4.99");
        System.out.println("3. Prawn Cocktail £9.99");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("\tMain Meals: ");
        System.out.println("4. Fish and Chips £12.50");
        System.out.println("5. Vegetarian Curry £9.90");
        System.out.println("6. Cottage Pie £11.50");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("\tDesserts: ");
        System.out.println("7. Trio of ice-cream £4.50");
        System.out.println("8. Apple Pie £5.20");
        System.out.println("9. Cheesecake £6.50");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("\tDrinks: ");
        System.out.println("10. Tea £2.99");
        System.out.println("11. Coffee £3.50");
        System.out.println("12. Lemonade £2.50");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("What would you like for starters? ");
        int custStarter = scanner.nextInt();
        if (custStarter == 1)
            System.out.println(starterMeal[0] + " £" + starterPrice[0]);
        else if (custStarter == 2)
            System.out.println(starterMeal[1] + " £" + starterPrice[1]);
        else
            System.out.println(starterMeal[2] + " £" + starterPrice[2]);

        System.out.println("What would you like for your main? ");
        int custMain = scanner.nextInt();
        if (custMain == 4)
            System.out.println(mainMeal[0] + " £" + mainPrice[0]);
        else if (custMain == 5)
            System.out.println(mainMeal[1] + " £" + mainPrice[1]);
        else
            System.out.println(mainMeal[2] + " £" + mainPrice[2]);

        System.out.println("What would you like dessert? ");
        int custDessert = scanner.nextInt();
        if (custDessert == 7)
            System.out.println(dessertMeal[0] + " £" + dessertPrice[0]);
        else if (custDessert == 8)
            System.out.println(dessertMeal[1] + " £" + dessertPrice[1]);
        else
            System.out.println(dessertMeal[2] + " £" + dessertPrice[2]);

        System.out.println("What would you like to drink? ");
        int custDrink = scanner.nextInt();
        if (custDrink == 10)
            System.out.println(drinkMeal[0] + " £" + drinkPrice[0]);
        else if (custDrink == 11)
            System.out.println(drinkMeal[1] + " £" + drinkPrice[1]);
        else
            System.out.println(drinkMeal[2] + " £" + drinkPrice[2]);
        

    }
}
```

Comment: They're numbers, and you're adding them. If you want to save what they've ordered you'd (currently) need to save each menu item as a string (you already have the index) somewhere, then put it back together at the end or build it as you go.

Comment: Unrelated: there's some great opportunities to clean up the code and reduce a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 0):

> convert the int that the user is inputting which relates to an item on the menu

You already did that several times.

```
System.out.println(starterMeal[0] + " £" + starterPrice[0]);
```

You can use `starterMeal[custStarter - 1]` instead...

> System.out.println(custStarter + custMain + custDessert + custDrink); just gives me the numbers inputted added together.

Yes. Unclear what else you expected by printing the sum of `int` variables.